# $.ajax no loading in IE8

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

Any ideas why IE8 isn't getting my Google Maps v3 response? Nothing is happening in IE8 - no errors or anything. It works fine in all other browsers.

```
    getLatLng:function(zip) {
            if (!zip) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var results = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zip + "&sensor=false",
                    dataType: "json",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function() {
                        maps.lat = $.parseJSON(results['responseText']).results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        maps.lng = $.parseJSON(results['responseText']).results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(maps.lat, maps.lng);
                        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: maps.setZoomLevel(),
                            center: latLng
                        }; //end mapOptions
                        maps.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                        maps.sql(zip, latLng);
                    } //end success
                }); //end ajax
            } //end if
        }, //end getLatLng
```

Comment: IE8 does not support json.  You can get past this by also including the file [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).  This will add in json support in browsers that do not support it.

Comment: IE8 does support json. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: Not really.   I have been down this route not too long ago where all was fine except in the IE8 browser.  After some digging I found that IE8 does not support it completely, even after reading the link you found.   In digging even deeper I found that once I added the json2.js to my project even IE8 worked.  As a side note we did not have json issues in ie8 until we changed our ajax to use parseJSON.  That is when we saw the issue.   IE9 also had issue but IE10+ are fine.

Comment: Still no dice for me even with json2.js. I think this might be a cross domain issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution for me. This plugin fixed this problem. And *I think* it was the Google Geocoding that was the problem. I also added crossDomain: true, to my script. Not sure if that really did anything or not, but it definitely didn't fix the problem on it's own.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="script/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```